# clip path in highcharts chart makes line invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, wicket

In my Java application I have a line chart of Highcharts. I can see that the chart and the line are created correctly, but the line is invisible. After using Firebug for some time, I found out that the clip path of the line elements is causing the problemens. When i remove the clip path, everything works as it should. Does anyone know what thi clip path is, where it is created and how I can prevent the creation?

Thanks in advance

Part of chart with clip path

```
 <g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
        <g class="highcharts-series" clip-path="url(http://localhost:8080/TEST/HvvKdhLBG_GOfT12f3Kh54IJiiZArBH0Chyl1i37kuIDMchs8P9Vf5Fk23LJVwIebtPVrBoSelg/Hvv97#highcharts-1)" visibility="visible" transform="translate(69,40)">
    </g>
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            var chart1; // globally available
            $(function()
            {
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart : {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
                    },
                    yAxis : {
                        title: {
                            x: -20
                        },
                        plotLines : [ {
                            value : 0,
                            width : 1,
                            color : '#808080'
                        } ]
                    },
                    xAxis : {
                        categories : [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
                    },
                    series : [ {
                        data : [ 29.9, null, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, null, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 ],
                    } ]
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I opened your example and `line series` is visible, but has gaps, because you use null values, so I'm not sure what is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/eunLz/

Comment: If I export it to pdf, it looks like this as well. But your version works because of the clip paths (firebug can see them). In your code I can see: clip-path="url(#highcharts-1)">, but in my code there is a larger string, which messes up my lines